# hide a set of divs from checkbox select

Tags: jquery

I have a complex form that i have created but i am having a brain fade when trying to construct a jQuery to hide a particular set of DIVS. What i want is for a these divs to hide when the checkbox is checked. The closest i have got is this

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQ) {
  jQ(".HideRow").click(function() {
    if (jQ(this).is(":checked")) {
      (jQ(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.hideme1, .hideme2, .hideme3').hide());
    } else {
      (jQ(this).closest('.wrapper').find('.hideme1, .hideme2, .hideme3').show());
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.form-group {
  clear: both;
}
.heading {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.header {
  float: left !important;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.donothideme {
  float: right !important;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
.hideme1 {
  Border: solid 2px blue;
  padding: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
  clear: both;
}
.hideme2 {
  Border: solid 2px green;
  padding: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
}
.hideme3 {
  Border: solid 2px yellow;
  padding: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
  color: #000;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="heading">
      <p></p>
      <div class="header">
        <h4>I do not want to hide</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="donothideme">
        <label for="NWDCheckbox" class="checkme">Check me...</label>
        <input name="Boxy" id="Boxy" value="Yes" class="HideRow CheckBox" type="checkbox">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hideme1">
    <p>
      I want To be Hidden
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hideme2">
    <p>
      Me to
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hideme3">
    <p>
      What about Me
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="header">
      <h4>I do not want to hide</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="donothideme">
      <label for="NWDCheckbox" class="checkme">Check me...</label>
      <input name="Boxy" id="Boxy" value="Yes" class="HideRow CheckBox" type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hideme1">
    <p>
      I want To be Hidden
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hideme2">
    <p>
      Me to
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hideme3">
    <p>
      What about Me
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="header">
      <h4>I do not want to hide</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="donothideme">
      <label for="NWDCheckbox" class="checkme">Check me...</label>
      <input name="Boxy" id="Boxy" value="Yes" class="HideRow CheckBox" type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hideme1">
    <p>
      I want To be Hidden
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hideme2">
    <p>
      Me to
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hideme3">
    <p>
      What about Me
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The above code is a rough guide to what i want to achieve
the fiddle is here https://jsfiddle.net/gpLxaj8y/

Comment: Your fiddle seems to be hiding all three sets of docs individually. Do you only want to hide one set for each box?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a wrapper element for each set of elements, one option is to wrap each set of elements with a wrapper then use `closest()` and `find()`.

But with the given markup, what you need to do is to select the next sibling elements of the current `form-group` element so

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(".HideRow").click(function() {
    $(this).closest('.form-group').nextUntil('.form-group', '.hideme1, .hideme2, .hideme3').toggle(!this.checked);
  });
});
```

```css
.form-group {
  clear: both;
}
.heading {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.header {
  float: left !important;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.donothideme {
  float: right !important;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 8px;
}
.hideme1 {
  Border: solid 2px blue;
  padding: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
  clear: both;
}
.hideme2 {
  Border: solid 2px green;
  padding: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
}
.hideme3 {
  Border: solid 2px yellow;
  padding: 10px 5px 5px 10px;
  color: #000;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="heading">
      <p></p>
      <div class="header">
        <h4>I do not want to hide</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="donothideme">
        <label for="NWDCheckbox" class="checkme">Check me...</label>
        <input name="Boxy" id="Boxy" value="Yes" class="HideRow CheckBox" type="checkbox">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hideme1">
    <p>
      I want To be Hidden
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hideme2">
    <p>
      Me to
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hideme3">
    <p>
      What about Me
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="header">
      <h4>I do not want to hide</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="donothideme">
      <label for="NWDCheckbox" class="checkme">Check me...</label>
      <input name="Boxy" id="Boxy" value="Yes" class="HideRow CheckBox" type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hideme1">
    <p>
      I want To be Hidden
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hideme2">
    <p>
      Me to
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hideme3">
    <p>
      What about Me
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="header">
      <h4>I do not want to hide</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="donothideme">
      <label for="NWDCheckbox" class="checkme">Check me...</label>
      <input name="Boxy" id="Boxy" value="Yes" class="HideRow CheckBox" type="checkbox">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hideme1">
    <p>
      I want To be Hidden
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hideme2">
    <p>
      Me to
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="hideme3">
    <p>
      What about Me
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution works,  but as newbie I am slightly confused as to how the selected divs are actually hidden as there is nowhere in the line of code that actually specifically says hide the divs ???

Comment: @ramakunga The [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle) method does that, if `true` is passed it will set display to show the item, if `false` is passed then it willbe hidden

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is very simple, you need to create a class and attach it to all the div's. Further using on change event toggle these divs.
Here is the jsfiddle for it

> CSS

```
 .hidden {
  display : block;
}
```

> Javascript

```
$('#chkbox').change(function(){
    $('.hidden').toggle();

});
```

See complete working code here
https://jsfiddle.net/avinash8526/a362u5px/